# scale_edge_colour_gradient legend not fully filled with colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

It seems my colour key legend is not fully filled with colour (*i.e.* all the way to 1 in this case). Furthermore, I am trying to position the key title (*i.e.* link strength) on top of the key rather than on the left.

```
ggraph(lay.ggraph) + 
 geom_edge_link0(aes(edge_colour = links$weight),
  edge_width = links$weight*10, lineend = "round") +
 scale_edge_color_gradient(name = "Link Strength",
  low = "#6495ED85", high = "#C1403D85") +
 geom_node_point(shape = 21, fill = "#D3D3D3", color = "#808080",
  size = 15, stroke = 2) +
 labs(y = "TL") +
 foodweb_theme`
```

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: I posted a workaround solution [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2465)

Comment: Thanks Thomas! You can also post an answer to your own question, and help others having a similar problem.